# How to set the SCHED_RR time slice or time quantum per process / thread?

Tags: scheduling, real-time, thread, round-robin

The time slice (also called time quantum) for threads with `SCHED_RR` policy can, according to the [sched_rr_get_interval man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_rr_get_interval.2.html) be obtained using

```
int sched_rr_get_interval(pid_t pid, struct timespec *tp);
```

This indicates that there could be different values set for different processes / threads.  According to [the same man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_rr_get_interval.2.html), however, the value can (since kernel 3.9) be adjusted using `/proc/sys/kernel/sched_rr_timeslice_ms`, which, however, does not seem to allow to change the configuration per thread in a sensible way.

Other places dealing with real-time scheduling also do not provide information how the time slice for `SCHED_RR` threads can be set per thread ([man chrt](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chrt.1.html), [man sched_setattr](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setattr.2.html), [SO: How to know linux scheduler time slice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16401294/5747415)).

It it possible to set the time slice individually per `SCHED_RR` thread?  If so, what is the preferred approach to do so?

Answer (score 2):

According to the man page you linked, `sched_rr_get_interval` conforms to the POSIX.1-2001 and POSIX.1-2008 standards. The POSIX standards thus allow different processes to have different time slice values, but as that same man page states: "POSIX does not specify any mechanism for controlling the size of the round-robin time quantum."

This might be the reason why there is no known way to set the round-robin time slice value per process or thread in Linux. As you noted, as far as I know and can find, it is only possible to change the time slice globally using `/proc/sys/kernel/sched_rr_timeslice_ms`.